# Discrete logarithm problem is easy in a cyclic group of order a power of two

Tags: reference-request, discrete-logarithm, group-theory

Let $G=\langle g\rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $2^{k}$ and let $h\in G$. I have read that it is easy to find $\log _{g} h$, but I haven't been able to figure out how. Do you know why this can be done in polynomial time? Do you know of a book where I can find this?

Comment: The [Pohlig-Hellman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) can be used to compute logarithms in groups of [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may find it useful to play around with a toy example, such as the integers modulo a Fermat prime, like $p = 257$.

Since $g$ is a generator of the Group, $h \equiv g^x$ for some unknown exponent $x$.  In other words, $\log_gh = x$, and for Groups of order $2^k$, this discrete log is easily computed like so:

Interpret $x$ as a $k$ bit number, i.e. $x = c_02^0 +c_12^1 + c_22^2 + c_32^3 ...+ c_{k}2^{k}$ where the coefficients $c_0, c_1, c_2...c_k \in \{0,1\}$.  You can find the value of $c_0$ by raising $g^x$ to the power $2^{k-1}$ modulo $p$.  If $c_0=0$ then all the other terms in $x$ are divisble by 2, thus $x=2y$, and so by Euler's totient theorem, $$(g^{2y})^{2^{k-1}}\equiv g^{y2^k} \equiv g^0 \equiv 1 \mod p$$
If however $c_0 = 1$, then raising $g^x$ to the power $2^{k-1}$ mod $p$ will return the result $p-1$.  So by looking at the result, you can see directly what the value of $c_0$ is.  Now that you have the value of $c_0$, subtract the term $c_02^0$ from $x$ (i.e. multiply $g^x$ by the modular multiplicative inverse of $g^{c_02^0}$).

Now you can find out what the value of $c_1$ is, by using the same approach:  raise $g^{x-c_02^0}$ to the power $2^{k-2}$.  If $c_1=0$, then all the remaining terms in $x-c_02^0$ are divisible by 4, and so $x-c_02^0 = 4y$ and $(g^{4y})^{2^{k-2}} \equiv g^{y2^k} \equiv 1 \mod p$.  If on the other hand $c_1=1$ then again the result will be $p-1$.  Subtract the term $c_12^1$ from $x-c_02^0$, and repeat the procedure for $c_2$.  Continue until you have discovered all the coefficients for $x$: you now know what $x$ is.

Comment: I must be missing something. If $G$ is a group and $g,h\in G$, what does $g^{h}$ mean?

Comment: @Howard - I think I initially misunderstood precisely what you were asking, but have clarified my answer.  Let me know if this is still not clear.